# when to use RecoveryCallback vs KafkaListenerErrorHandler

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to understand when should i use org.springframework.retry.RecoveryCallback and org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaListenerErrorHandler?

As of today, I'm using a class (implements org.springframework.retry.RecoveryCallback) to log error message and send the message to DLT and it's working. For sending a message to DLT, I'm using Spring KafkaTemplate and then I came across KafkaListenerErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer. Now, can you please suggest me, how should i use KafkaListenerErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer? Can this replace the RecoveryCallback?

Here is my current kafkaListenerContainerFactory code

> @Bean
>   public  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
>
> ```
> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
>
> factory.setConsumerFactory(primaryConsumerFactory());
> factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
> factory.setRecoveryCallback(recoveryCallback);
> factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
> factory.setConcurrency(1);  
> factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
> return factory;   }
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's working as you want now, why change it?

There are several layers and you can choose which one to do the error handling, depending on your needs.

- `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` would be invoked for each delivery attempt within the retry, so you typically won't use it with retry.
- Retry `RecoveryCallback` is invoked after retries are exhausted (or immmediately if you have classified an exception as not retryable).
- `ErrorHandler` - is in the container and is invoked if any listener throws an exception, not just `@KafkaListener`s.

With recent versions of the framework you can completely replace listener level retry with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` configured with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` and a `BackOff`.

The `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` is intended for use in a container error handler since it needs the raw `ConsumerRecord<?, ?>`.

The `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` only has access to the spring-messaging `Message<?>` that is converted from the `ConsumerRecord<?, ?>`.

Comment: Can we use both RecoveryCallback and ErrorHandler in the same time ?

Comment: Retry at the listener level is deprecated, now that the error handlers have much more sophistication. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1886

Comment: @GaryRussell `RecoveryCallback` does not have access to the record, what if I want to execute a logic for records after retries are exhausted?

Comment: I think I can get the record from attributes `retryContext.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD);`

Comment: One more time; it is deprecated and won't be available at all in 3.0.

Comment: Sorry for circling back to the same question.So how can I access the ConsumerRecord in the RecoveryCallback? Or back to my previous question how to execute a logic on a ConsumerRecord when retries are exhausted?

Comment: You answered your own question 2 comments up.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to the excellent context from *@GaryRussell*, this is what i am currently using:

I am handling any errors(a.k.a exception) like this:

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
```

And to print this error, i have a listener on the `.DLT` and i am printing the exception stack trace that is stored in the header like so:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "MY_ID", topics = MY_TOPIC + ".DLT")
public void listenDlt(ConsumerRecord<String, SomeClassName> consumerRecord,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.DLT_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE) String exceptionStackTrace) {
            
    logger.error(exceptionStackTrace);
}
```

**Note:**
 I am using *logger.error*, because i am redirecting all error messages to an error log file that is being monitored.

**BONUS:**
If you set the following:
`logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=DEBUG`

You will see this in your console/log:

```
xxx [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#7-2-C-1] DEBUG o.s.k.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler - Skipping seek of: ConsumerRecord xxx
xxx [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-3] DEBUG o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer - Successful dead-letter publication: SendResult xxx
```

If you have a *better way to log*, i would appreciate your comment.
Thanks!

Cheers